# PHP multiple arrays combinations Create URLs

Tags: php, combinations

I am trying to collect a film and television resources website, resource list there are four optional drop-down box filter, trying to use PHP simulated users, iterate through all the filtering, and generate the link under the circumstance of each filter.

Generated link to at least one kind of filters, each filter can be used only once, at most there are four filters, filter not difference successively in the link.

Generate links, regular matching: (Parameters are at least 1 and up to 4)

```
URL/(?:class_(movie|tv)/)*(?:year_(2013|2012|2011|2010|2009)/)*(?:region_region(‌​1|2)/)*(?:genre_region(1|2)/)*
```

Sorry, English is not good, use GOGOLE translate.

Four kinds of filter the data as below : (Part of the data)

```
$class  = array('movie', 'tv');
$year   = array(2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009);
$region = array('region1', 'region2');
$genre  = array('genre1', 'genre2');
```

I'd like to generate an array contains all the filter link.

Want to get the following some of the data: (Part of the data)

```
Array
(
    [0] => URL/class_movie/
    [1] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/
    [2] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/
    [3] => URL/class_movie/region_region1/
    [4] => URL/class_movie/region_region2/
    [5] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region1/
    [6] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region2/
    [7] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region1/
    [8] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region2/
    [9] => URL/class_movie/year_2013/
    [10] => URL/class_movie/year_2012/
    [11] => URL/class_movie/year_2011/
    [12] => URL/class_movie/year_2010/
    [13] => URL/class_movie/year_2009/
    [14] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/year_2013/
    [15] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/year_2012/
    [16] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/year_2011/
    [17] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/year_2010/
    [18] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/year_2009/
    [19] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/year_2013/
    [20] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/year_2012/
    [21] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/year_2011/
    [22] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/year_2010/
    [23] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/year_2009/
    [24] => URL/class_movie/region_region1/year_2013/
    [25] => URL/class_movie/region_region1/year_2012/
    [26] => URL/class_movie/region_region1/year_2011/
    [27] => URL/class_movie/region_region1/year_2010/
    [28] => URL/class_movie/region_region1/year_2009/
    [29] => URL/class_movie/region_region2/year_2013/
    [30] => URL/class_movie/region_region2/year_2012/
    [31] => URL/class_movie/region_region2/year_2011/
    [32] => URL/class_movie/region_region2/year_2010/
    [33] => URL/class_movie/region_region2/year_2009/
    [34] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2013/
    [35] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2012/
    [36] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2011/
    [37] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2010/
    [38] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2009/
    [39] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2013/
    [40] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2012/
    [41] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2011/
    [42] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2010/
    [43] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2009/
    [44] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2013/
    [45] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2012/
    [46] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2011/
    [47] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2010/
    [48] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2009/
    [49] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2013/
    [50] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2012/
    [51] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2011/
    [52] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2010/
    [53] => URL/class_movie/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2009/
    [54] => URL/class_tv/
    [55] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/
    [56] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/
    [57] => URL/class_tv/region_region1/
    [58] => URL/class_tv/region_region2/
    [59] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region1/
    [60] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region2/
    [61] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region1/
    [62] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region2/
    [63] => URL/class_tv/year_2013/
    [64] => URL/class_tv/year_2012/
    [65] => URL/class_tv/year_2011/
    [66] => URL/class_tv/year_2010/
    [67] => URL/class_tv/year_2009/
    [68] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/year_2013/
    [69] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/year_2012/
    [70] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/year_2011/
    [71] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/year_2010/
    [72] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/year_2009/
    [73] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/year_2013/
    [74] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/year_2012/
    [75] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/year_2011/
    [76] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/year_2010/
    [77] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/year_2009/
    [78] => URL/class_tv/region_region1/year_2013/
    [79] => URL/class_tv/region_region1/year_2012/
    [80] => URL/class_tv/region_region1/year_2011/
    [81] => URL/class_tv/region_region1/year_2010/
    [82] => URL/class_tv/region_region1/year_2009/
    [83] => URL/class_tv/region_region2/year_2013/
    [84] => URL/class_tv/region_region2/year_2012/
    [85] => URL/class_tv/region_region2/year_2011/
    [86] => URL/class_tv/region_region2/year_2010/
    [87] => URL/class_tv/region_region2/year_2009/
    [88] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2013/
    [89] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2012/
    [90] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2011/
    [91] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2010/
    [92] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region1/year_2009/
    [93] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2013/
    [94] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2012/
    [95] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2011/
    [96] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2010/
    [97] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/region_region2/year_2009/
    [98] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2013/
    [99] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2012/
    [100] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2011/
    [101] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2010/
    [102] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region1/year_2009/
    [103] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2013/
    [104] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2012/
    [105] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2011/
    [106] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2010/
    [107] => URL/class_tv/genre_genre2/region_region2/year_2009/
    [108] => URL/year_2013/
    [109] => URL/year_2013/genre_genre1/
    [110] => URL/year_2013/genre_genre2/
    [111] => URL/year_2013/region_region1/
    [112] => URL/year_2013/region_region2/
    [113] => URL/year_2013/genre_genre1/region_region1/
    [114] => URL/year_2013/genre_genre1/region_region2/
    [115] => URL/year_2013/genre_genre2/region_region1/
    [116] => URL/year_2013/genre_genre2/region_region2/
    [117] => URL/year_2012/
    [118] => URL/year_2012/genre_genre1/
    [119] => URL/year_2012/genre_genre2/
    [120] => URL/year_2012/region_region1/
    [121] => URL/year_2012/region_region2/
    [122] => URL/year_2012/genre_genre1/region_region1/
    [123] => URL/year_2012/genre_genre1/region_region2/
    [124] => URL/year_2012/genre_genre2/region_region1/
    [125] => URL/year_2012/genre_genre2/region_region2/
    [126] => URL/year_2011/
    [127] => URL/year_2011/genre_genre1/
    [128] => URL/year_2011/genre_genre2/
    [129] => URL/year_2011/region_region1/
    [130] => URL/year_2011/region_region2/
    [131] => URL/year_2011/genre_genre1/region_region1/
    [132] => URL/year_2011/genre_genre1/region_region2/
    [133] => URL/year_2011/genre_genre2/region_region1/
    [134] => URL/year_2011/genre_genre2/region_region2/
    [135] => URL/year_2010/
    [136] => URL/year_2010/genre_genre1/
    [137] => URL/year_2010/genre_genre2/
    [138] => URL/year_2010/region_region1/
    [139] => URL/year_2010/region_region2/
    [140] => URL/year_2010/genre_genre1/region_region1/
    [141] => URL/year_2010/genre_genre1/region_region2/
    [142] => URL/year_2010/genre_genre2/region_region1/
    [143] => URL/year_2010/genre_genre2/region_region2/
    [144] => URL/year_2009/
    [145] => URL/year_2009/genre_genre1/
    [146] => URL/year_2009/genre_genre2/
    [147] => URL/year_2009/region_region1/
    [148] => URL/year_2009/region_region2/
    [149] => URL/year_2009/genre_genre1/region_region1/
    [150] => URL/year_2009/genre_genre1/region_region2/
    [151] => URL/year_2009/genre_genre2/region_region1/
    [152] => URL/year_2009/genre_genre2/region_region2/
    [153] => URL/region_region1/
    [154] => URL/region_region1/genre_genre1/
    [155] => URL/region_region1/genre_genre2/
    [156] => URL/region_region2/
    [157] => URL/region_region2/genre_genre1/
    [158] => URL/region_region2/genre_genre2/
    [159] => URL/genre_genre1/
    [160] => URL/genre_genre2/
)
```

URL/year_2013/region_region1/ equal URL/region_region1/year_2013/

Comment: `I have the 3 arrays` I thought you have 5 :)

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. We are not a code generation service.

Comment: @swapnesh
is the result of the search link below:
http://goo.gl/mGp3p
http://goo.gl/1hWcZ
http://goo.gl/SjRPI
http://goo.gl/3xfr0
http://goo.gl/f2kK8
They are all take an array of values

Comment: @verglas I just updated my answer...plz chk if this is what you are loking for

Comment: @MarcB,@M42,@Marc B,@Sean,@Gabe Sechan,@swapnesh,@m42
Hello, I have improved the problem, tell the cause of the problem, corrects the demo code, also added a detailed problem description.Please help to cancel the on hold, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for --

**EDIT 3** (Final Edit - please dont change your question too frequently, I still created this solution from your initial edit of `class_tv` and NOT `tv`)

Code working and checked with all your mentioned URLs -

```
<?php
$class = array('movie', 'tv');
$year = array(2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009);
$region = array('region1', 'region2');
$genre = array('genre1', 'genre2');
$i=1;

$myarr = array();
foreach($class as $myclass)
{
    $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/';
    foreach($year as $myyear)
    {
        $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'year_'.$myyear.'/';
        $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/year_'.$myyear.'/';
        foreach($region as $myregion)
        {
        $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'/region_'.$myregion.'/';
        $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/region_'.$myregion.'/';
        $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'/year_'.$myyear.'/region_'.$myregion.'/';    
        $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/year_'.$myyear.'/region_'.$myregion.'/';
            foreach($genre as $mygenre)
            {
                $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'/genre_'.$mygenre.'/';
                $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/genre_'.$mygenre.'/';
                $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/year_'.$myyear.'/genre_'.$mygenre.'/';
                $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/region_'.$myregion.'/genre_'.$mygenre.'/';
                $myarr[] = 'URL/'.'class_'.$myclass.'/year_'.$myyear.'/region_'.$myregion.'/genre_'.$mygenre.'/';               
            }
        }
    }
}

$myarr = array_unique($myarr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarr);
```

**Tested Links -**

```
URL/class_movie/
URL/class_movie/year_2013/
URL/class_movie/year_2013/region_region1/
URL/class_movie/year_2013/region_region1/genre_genre1/
URL/class_movie/region_region1/
URL/class_movie/region_region1/genre_genre1/
URL/class_movie/genre_genre1/
URL/class_tv/
URL/class_tv/year_2013/
URL/class_tv/year_2013/region_region1/
URL/class_tv/year_2013/region_region1/genre_genre1/
URL/class_tv/region_region1/
URL/class_tv/region_region1/genre_genre1/
URL/class_tv/genre_genre1/
```

Comment: +1 straight forward solution, the only missing piece is a null version for each the year, genre and region as shown in the example.

Comment: @Orangepill hey how r u ? :) ..thx for the eagle eyes :) ..let me update my answer

Comment: Can need not nested loop implementation?
Some problems, such as:
URL/class_movie/year_2013/region_region2/genre_genre1 not exists

Comment: @verglas Please check my updated answer with the link, i hope it will help you to iterate over with what you are looking for

Comment: @swapnesh thanks, Sorry, English is not good. Your case, each array can take a value, to combine. The difference is that I am required at least two arrays can take a value, to combine. Question I also search before

Comment: @verglas let me update my answer then

Comment: @verglas Please check my recent edit in the answer and let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: @swapnesh URL/(?:class_(movie|tv)/)*(?:year_(2013|2012|2011|2010|2009)/)*(?:region_region(1|2)/)*(?:genre_region(1|2)/)*
BUT Parameters are at least 1 and up to 4

Comment: @verglas You can easily iterate over the array, in the above format and merge the results then for these(added in my answer)

Comment: @swapnesh thanks, Production environment, the array is larger. And traverse the four cannot obtain all parameters combination. May I mean I didn't say understand, you can see above my reply under the regular expression.

Comment: @verglas Please check my latest, i hope it will meet all your conditions now

Comment: @swapnesh Sorry, I didn't say understand. Four parameters, no subordinate relationship, link only requires at least one arbitrary parameter in up to four parameters.I have modified the ask.For example, the following link and you can't generate:URL/region1/. I think, a nested loop cannot be completed

Comment: @swapnesh can you help me modify title is more appropriate. it is not duplicate. thank you

Comment: @verglas i deleted and working on your request..let give me 10-15 min..will post a solution soon :)

Comment: @verglas You changed `URL/class_tv/` with `URL/tv/` now..please specific with your requirement

Comment: @swapnesh Sorry, forgot to add prefix when batch replacement. I think the nested loop can't solve.

Comment: @verglas why?? I check all with the above mentioned links...and its working? any subset not coming can be made available i guess..let me know which pattern is still missing

Comment: @swapnesh very Sorry, it seems that the output of the example I let you misunderstanding, the same link, four parameters, each of the parameters appear at most once, a link to at least have a parameter.I have modified the ask.